# Pass this(a button html element) to "onclick" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I create dynamically a new row of a table using jQuery:

```
    addRowToTable() {
        $('.table > tbody:last-child').append(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td name="name1" contenteditable="true"></td>' +
            '<td name="name2" contenteditable="true"></td>' +
            '<td name="name3" contenteditable="true"></td>' +
            '<td name="name4" contenteditable="true"></td>' +
            '<td id="save">' +
            '<button>save</button>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td id="delete-row">' +
            '<button onclick="deleteRowFromTable($(this))">delete</button>' +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
        );
    }
```

Here is my `deleteRowFromTable(deleteRowButton)`:

```
deleteRowFromTable(deleteRowButton) {
    $(deleteRowButton).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

,it's in the same class as the `addRowToTable` method.
And i'd like to pass a button in the `onclick` attribute.
I tried both `onclick="deleteRowFromTable($(this))"` and `onclick="deleteRowFromTable(this)"` - none of them works.
Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Your code suggests that you're creating multiple elements with the same `id` (of `"delete-row"`), this will result in invalid HTML and impair your JavaScript functionality. Incidentally, rather than littering your HTML with JavaScript why not use JavaScript to add the event-handling, either through [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or jQuery's [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method?

Comment: While I agree with David's comment above, that is not your issue for sure. From what I see, your code should work... See [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wvzGRQB). --- Do you use the `function` keyword to declare the functions?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica really good idea. Gonna work on it, thank you =)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i'm using js classes, keyword 'function' not allowed there

Answer (score 0):

Assign the id ="delete-row" to the button and pass button id 'this.id' to deleteRowFromTable function as shown below.

```
addRowToTable() {
    $('.table > tbody:last-child').append(
        '<tr>' +
        '<td name="name1" contenteditable="true"></td>' +
        '<td name="name2" contenteditable="true"></td>' +
        '<td name="name3" contenteditable="true"></td>' +
        '<td name="name4" contenteditable="true"></td>' +
        '<td id="save">' +
        '<button>save</button>' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<button id="delete-row" onclick="deleteRowFromTable(this.id)">delete</button>' +
        '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
    );
}

deleteRowFromTable(id) {
    $('#'+id).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Comment: Adding id is bad - this will break everything if i add multiple rows